# My refactored vanilla JS button click is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am working in refactoring a jQuery web sdk into a vanilla JavaScript one.

The original jQuery file has a button click like so:

```
sdk.initialize().then(function() {
  $('#loginButton').click(function() {
    // more logic in here
  });
});
```

I started my refactor like so:

```
sdk.initialize().then(() => {
  document.querySelector('#loginButton').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('you clicked me!');
  });
});
```

If the code looks right, then it might be a scope issue, as this is inside of RequireJS like so:

```
require(['XmSdk', 'XmUIHandler'], (xm, xmui) => {
  const sdk = XmSdk();
  // the above code resides in here
});
```

When I click on the button, I get no output and no error.

I even tried this:

```
sdk.initialize().then(() => {
  console.log('initialized!');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('Failed to initialize');
});
```

and I get no output and no error.

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues with the code. Is there an error? Or just no output when you click?

Comment: @BrandonGano, there is no output

Comment: are u sure the initialize part was called? try doing a console.log("hi") right outside the document.querySelector part, t osee if the promise was fulfilled, also maybe add a .catch at the end

Comment: @bluejayke, just added the catch, shared what I did in OP.

Comment: OK if you get no output and no erro rthat means the promise was never fulfilled and never rejected, so that means there is a problem with the `sdk.initialize()` code, and in order for us to solve that we would need to see the source for that function

Comment: also I don't know why you do `const sdk = XmSdk();` if you pass in the variable, as the first parameter, as `xm`, shouldn't it be something like `const sdk = xm.XmSdk()` ?

Comment: @bluejayke, according to the guide they document it as `const sdk = XmSdk();`. I believe the problem is with the library I have imported `import { XmSdk } from './xm/js-es6/xmsdk-es6.js';` I believe there is a bug with the library itself in that there is no `XmSdk` object to pull out of there.

Comment: OK can you post a link to the guide you are referring to, and a link to your full code (or copy and paste the full code) here?

Comment: if you're using import then why are you also using `require`?

Comment: also perhaps try changing the main prmise resolve arrow function to `function` just so its exactly like your jquery example, I have no idea what that library does, if it stringifies the function and looks for the keyword "function", try the code `sdk.initialize().then(function() { console.log("hi") }).catch(function(err) { console.log(err) });`

Comment: @bluejayke, you hit on it when you asked me if I am using `import` statements why then use RequireJS. For RequireJS, I was just following the guide, I just started learning about it, so I removed it because I really don't use in my career and sure enough, `sdk.authenticate()` is initialized and the button click code I have in the OP works now.

Comment: @Daniel cool to hear it all worked out :)

Answer (score -3):

try with a function instead, not an arrow function on event handler

```js
sdk.initialize().then(() => {
  document.querySelector('#loginButton').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('you clicked me!');
  });
});
```

Comment: why? arrray functions are used with event handlers al the time, and there is no `this` operator used

Comment: that has happened to me in the past, when I made that refactoring, it works, actually I don't know why yet.